# Lean 3 immediately hangs on import statements

Tags: importerror, freeze, lean

I am attempting to use Lean's `mathlib`, however on import it fails. When I write `#print notation` on a file without any import statements, it executes; if I include the same command on a file with even just a single `import data.real.basic`, the program hangs without printing anything. Any assistance with fixing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Patrick's answer below is correct, the situation is probably that you did not follow the instructions to the letter and because right now the instructions are quite long so it's hard to figure out how to fix things. What is *probably* happening is that you have either got an uncompiled mathlib, or compiled binaries which are incompatible with either your mathlib or your lean (so it's compiling, not hanging). Try typing `leanproject up` in the root directory of your project, or `leanproject get-cache` or `leanproject get-mathlib-cache`, you might be lucky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a path error.

`leanproject` didn't exist (or so I thought, it was actually just never added to `$PATH`) so I attempted to add `mathlib` using `leanpkg`.

It ended up pulling the whole thing from the git every time I tried to execute any files, and compiling it (taking upwards of an hour).